# PHP does not execute if i do not provide the index file manually

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I know the title may be a little confusing, so let me explain.

I had Apache2 with PHP7.0  and Mysql, working perfectly fine, I duplicated my VM and attempted to install an SSL certificate on one, Lets just say that didnt go well and i had to reinstall apache2 and php7.0.

Now, if i go to my website like this: `http://example.com/` Then the php DOES NOT execute, However, If i visit `http://example.com/index.php`, then it works perfectly fine. Also, I am just pointing out that i am saying that the PHP doesnt execute, the page itself(The HTML of the index.php) shows up without a problem.

Also, i am currently on Ubuntu 16.

Anyone have any idea? thanks!

I seemed to have fixed the problem:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The ".php$" was not inside of quotations, placing them inside quotes seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have configured a default page in Apache, search for "apache DirectoryIndex".

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez I have added index.php as a DirectoryIndex, When i load "http://example.com/" it loads the default index.php, its just the php code doesnt execute

Comment: It still sounds like a server configuration problem, not a programming problem, so ServerFault.com would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If php is not executing (you get source code back), that means that apache is not sending php requests to mod_php.  This is probably caused by a missconfigured `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so` OR 
`AddHandler php5-script .php`

Comment: @AlexBarker As stated above, PHP is executing but ONLY if i provide the index.php in the url. If i do not provide the index.php, it only shows the html of the index.php with the php printed and not executed, Also, i am using PHP7.0

Comment: @DanielSaunders if you are seeing php src code, the webserver __is not__ executing PHP.  If you are not seeing php src, and php is indeed running the code, then some other file is being loaded, maybe index.html or default.html.  Check your DirectoryIndex as mentioned, remember order does matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the config for you domain (probably in httpd.conf) and add the following:

```
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
</VirtualHost>
```

For example:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
ServerName mysite
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite">
allow from all
order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html 
</VirtualHost
```

This will tell Apache that index.php is your preferred index file.